# encoding in python and writing it to a YAML file in Python

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, pyyaml

I have a Unicode, which is read from a CSV file:

```
df.iloc[0,1]
Out[41]: u'EU-repr\xe6sentant udpeget'

In [42]: type(df_translated.iloc[0,1])
Out[42]: unicode
```

I would like to have it as `EU-repræsentant udpeget`. The final goal is to write this into a dictionary and then finally save that dict to a YAML file with `PyYAML` using `safe_dump`. However, I struggle with the encoding.

Comment: The `yaml` utility (installable by using pip install `ruamel.yaml.cmd` has an option to convert from CSV to YAML and it handles the unicode correctly (but it is based on ruamel.yaml generating YAML 1.2 and not on PyYAML (generating YAML 1.1 documents).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to use PyYAML you should provide the arguments
`encoding='utf-8'` and `allow_unicode=True` to the `safe_dump()`
routine.

If you ever intend to upgrade to YAML 1.2 and use ruamel.yaml
(disclaimer: I am the author of that package), those are the (much
more sensible) defaults:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

data = [u'EU-repr\xe6sentant udpeget']
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- EU-repræsentant udpeget
```